# Metro style apps with Html and C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

According to this slide

http://media.infragistics.com/community/general/windows8-platform-tools.jpg

Does it mean I have to use XAML view with C# if I want to develop a metro styled application?

Can I use a HTML/JS/CSS - C# combination with event handlers and all? Something like ASP.NET Webforms/MVC . I know it is not the same client server architecture, but since metro styled apps support HTML/JS, I was wondering.

I can use Win-JS. But can I rather write C# than Javascript, and use HTML rather than XAML?(I dont know XAML and I like C#)

All the C# samples I found online use XAML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you can write portions of your program logic in C# and package it as a library and then create a HTML5/JS app that references the C# Library. That way you should only need to use JS for the parts that are directly related to UI functions and C# for the rest.

I will point out that I haven't tried it yet, but Bill in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/e890e461-a6fc-4396-8a27-57ed090998a5) says that he got it to work.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can only use XAML with C#, or HTML+CSS+JS. But XAML is great markup language, so I think you able to use it.

Comment: Don't write answers before you search it :) Look at my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a "WinMD" library in c# (or c++) that can be invoked from JavaScript.  There are a ton of limitations that WinMD libraries have over normal .net libraries and the usage model would be would at all like ASP.NET MVC.  Frankly, unless you have a lot of business logic in c# already or if you want to reuse a bunch of code in Win8 Metro apps spanning both HTML and XAML, this WinMD thing is more hassle than its worth.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN - Dev Center - Metro style apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/) you can use `C#/VB/C++ and XAML` and `JavaScript and HTML5` to develop a metro styled application (for Windows8/WindowsPhone).